# I am unable to read content from .txt file using StreamReader class of c#

Tags: c#, streamreader, notsupportedexception

Here is my code..I am trying to read data from .txt file which was stored in music folder. But i am getting some error like,
System.NotSupportedException.
The given path's format is not supported.

Please help...........

```
string path = @"Music:\streamfile.txt";

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
{
    String s = "";

    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I agree - `@"Music:\streamfile.txt";` doesn't look like a valid path; where is it *actually*. Note: the current user's `Music` folder is: `%USERPROFILE%\Music`, so you might want `@"%USERPROFILE%\Music\streamfile.txt"` - but you might need to do an env expand first, not sure - try it!

Comment: ThisPC > Music in windows 10

Comment: "ThisPC > Music" is simply a lie to keep things simple for casual users; you probably mean `%USERPROFILE%\Music`

Comment: Go to the file system and see the properties of the file. There you can see the real path. Use that one. The music folder is an abstraction not available to your code.

Comment: Actually i dont have Local Folder that's why i placed my file in that folder.

Comment: Is there any way to store that file so that i can read data from it.

Comment: To check if the problem is actually the path itself, I suggest you put your file inside of your Bin>Debug folder of your project. Then, in your code, use this path: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "streamfile.txt"`

Comment: I have changed my file path,New path is    string path = @"C:\Users\daye3\Desktop\Study Project\c# stuff:\streamfile.txt"; still facing same issue

Comment: I changed my path  string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"),
              "Music", "streamfile.txt");    Now it's working....Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list with 'special' folders somewhere but you can construct it yourself:

```
  string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"),
           "Music", "streamfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `Environment.GetFolderPath`

```
//if you want windows common music folder ex:C:\Users\Public\Music\streamfile.txt
var CommonMusicPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonMusic) + @"\streamfile.txt"; 
//if you want windows user music folder ex:C:\Users\username\Music\streamfile.txt
var MyUserMusicPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic) + @"\streamfile.txt"; 
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(MyUserMusicPath))
{
    String s = "";

    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```